# to access Javascript object key value

Tags: javascript, object, properties

hello guys i'm  beginner of javascript!
I know  there are two ways to get object value

if there is object

```
object = {
   1:"one",
   2:"two".
}
```

1st : object.1
2nd : object[1]

but i wonder why this code has error

```
var product = {
    1:{title:'The history of web'},
    2:{title:'The next web'}
};

for(var name in product){
    product[name].title -> OK
    product.name.title -> error!!
}
```

what is difference between two codes!

Comment: `product[name]` is used to access property dynamically. Here `name` will be replaced by it's value and that property is searched in `product`. `product.name` will search for `name` property in `product` which doesn't exists, so result will be `undefined` and you cannot access `title` of `undefined`.

Comment: thanks a lot to your knowledge and kindness...!! thanks!!!

Comment: and may i ask one more question?
var user{
    username:'aaa',
    password:'1111'
}
user.username -> OK
but user[username] is error 
what is the problem?

Comment: As explained in previous comment, when using bracket notation, the value of variable is replaced by it's value, i.e. `undefined` in this case, thus error. You need to wrap it in quotes `user['username']`.

Comment: it should be user["username"]  single quatation is not accepted